# Static method for visible attributes in laravel

Tags: laravel, recursion, eloquent, visibility

I made a simple trait, that let you define visible attributes when serializing model: https://gist.github.com/kticka/1b960d2175d89de0cb36568f67aa4a73

Laravel has setVisible, setHidden methods, but they are for instances, so you need to iterate through objects to set attributes on each instance. Thats would be OK, but while I'm working with 'recursive' relationships, it became painful.

I would like to ask maybe I missed something and there is native way to do this.